# Scrollview with fixed header (android) setCanceledOnTouchOutside doesn't work

Tags: android, android-layout, android-alertdialog

I have dialog based on scrollview with fixed header. I need to set canceled on touch outside, but it does not work. (When I use only ScrollView without header, setCanceledOnTouchOutside works correct)

Dialog layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="0dp"
        android:paddingBottom="0dp">
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/shareFrameLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="0dp">
           ///fixed header
            ...
        </FrameLayout>
        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/SharePostScrollView"
            android:layout_below="@+id/shareFrameLayout">
            ...
    </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

`setCanceledOnTouchOutside:` `(setLayout(275, 350)` also doesn't work)

```
 @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        if (getDialog() != null) {
            getDialog().setCancelable(true);
            getDialog().setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
            getDialog().getWindow().setLayout(275, 350);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by replacing code from onViewCreated into onStart